# CSS file to include only in single page Rails not working on Server

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails

I have included a css file for styling of pdf.
I can't add this in tree as it will override styles, used on on other pages.

So I include the pdf.css is app/assets/stylesheets.

and in head of view i.e pdf_format.slim I added

```
link href='/assets/pdf.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'
```

It works ok on local machine but on server it seems that it didn't found css.

How to give path to css file in such case.

Comment: have you added this css file to `Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( pdf.css )` ? & have you precompiled assets in production server ?

Comment: no, I don't have Idea about this, in which file I have to write this line?

Comment: In Rails 4, there is a specific file `config/initializers/assets.rb`, there you can add this OR you can add this to `config/application.rb`

Comment: Yes I found assets.rb, going to change a deploy on server.
I hope that it will work

Comment: Make sure you precompile production assets using `rake assets:precompile` after deployment.

Comment: @dkp I deployed it in Cloud66, It didn't worked.
But I 'm not sure that whether Cloud66 precompiles assets or not at each development

Answer (score 0):

Need to add this to `config/initializers/assets.rb`:

```
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( pdf.css )
```

And, precompile production assets :

```
rake assets:precompile
```

[Refer Asset Pipeline in Production](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#in-production)

Comment: I deployed it in Cloud66, It didn't worked. But I 'm not sure that whether Cloud66 precompiles assets or not at each deployment.
Moreover I 'm testing on Development server on Cloud66 before going to Production Server.

Comment: Please check if this could give you a lead: http://help.cloud66.com/building-your-stack/asset-pipeline-compilation

Comment: I 'm on development environment on server for testing.
css not working there